# Is it possible to create and catch a custom exception based on the contents of another exception?

Tags: sqlalchemy

I have an annoying and unfixable problem with a database outside of my control which often times out on me. The result is that several times a day I get a very verbose OperationalError with a full call stack dump, inside which I find the "SQL server timeout" message.

I wonder if it were possible to create my own exception, "StupidTimeoutError" and then add some smartness to automatically catch any OperationalErrors, parse its message, and, if it's a timeout, raise StupidTimeoutError, and if it's not, reraise the original exception.

Currently I'm using something like this, where is_sql_timeout() basically just checks the error message against a regex:

```
try:
    db.query()...
except OperationalError as e:
    if is_sql_timeout(e):
        # deal with it
    else:
        ....
```

Come to think of it, maybe it's better to just stick with this simple approach. The other idea may look more elegant but needs to hook somewhere into the whole exception raising chain which ultimately may make it less maintainable.